# SQL query to show only duplicate entry based of a column value, result should bring in all column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need some help please with my SQL Server query.

I have a SQL Server table and I wanted to get all column data if `Employee_Number` column has more than one record; if it has only unique value then I don't want to get it displayed.

From below example, `Employee_Number` column has duplicates values of `1111111` and `3333333`. So it displayed all the records of duplicate values including all the rest of column values.

The data pasted below looks like scattered, so I have shown as an image too (my data and expected output)

Actual data in SQL Server:

```
userid  Gecos   B2A_LDAP    AD  Employee_Number B2A_CN  absJobAction    Generic_OR_User Unix_ID Additional_ID_in_Unix   Application_Access
user1   user one    user1   user1   1111111 user one    HIRED   User    user1   NULL    NULL
user2   user two    user2   user2   2222222 user two    HIRED   User    user2   NULL    NULL
user11  user one additional user1   user1   1111111 user one    HIRED   User    user11  NULL    NULL
user3   user three  user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user3   NULL    NULL
user33  user three spare ID 1   user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user33  NULL    NULL
user4   user four   user4   user4   4444444 user four   HIRED   User    user4   NULL    NULL
user333 user three spare ID 3   user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user333 NULL    NULL
```

My expected output should be as below.

```
userid  Gecos   B2A_LDAP    AD  Employee_Number B2A_CN  absJobAction    Generic_OR_User Unix_ID Additional_ID_in_Unix   Application_Access
user1   user one    user1   user1   1111111 user one    HIRED   User    user1   NULL    NULL
user11  user one additional user1   user1   1111111 user one    HIRED   User    user11  NULL    NULL
user3   user three  user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user3   NULL    NULL
user33  user three spare ID 1   user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user33  NULL    NULL
user333 user three spare ID 3   user3   user3   3333333 user three  HIRED   User    user333 NULL    NULL
```

[Data in SQL Server table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg8Zn.png)

[My expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dniLY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 10 * 
from Shipping_Bill a
join 
    (select sb_number 
     from Shipping_Bill 
     group by SB_Number  
     having count(*) > 1) b on a.SB_Number = b.SB_Number
```

Please try this query. It will help you.

Comment: Oh my boy this worked, awesome, thanks so much....in my employee_number column there were many cells with NA so that too came in result but thats fine, I can remove those from excel.

Comment: Is there a way I can eliminate the duplicate entry on employee_number that has N/A as the value, because few employee as employee number as N/A so that too coming in the output. if its too much work from your side, thats fine..I will remove from excel.

Comment: @Binish if this is the solution please accept the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, 
It will work if userId  column is unique in the table.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM UserMst
    WHERE EmployeeNumber IN (   SELECT EmployeeNumber 
                        FROM UserMst
                        GROUP BY EmployeeNumber
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: sorry I missed something in question, please see edited query

Comment: Nope didnt work, your query showing only unique values.. I got the answer from Chetan Gharat and Triv.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to find users that have duplicated `Employee_Number`

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM YourUserTable y
 WHERE Employee_Number IN ( SELECT y1.Employee_Number 
                   FROM YourUserTable y1
                   GROUP BY y1.Employee_Number
                   HAVING count(*) > 1
                   )
```